# Tabs to spaces + GIT

Tags: git

I work on a project with a few other developers. Not everybody uses the same IDE. Recently I realized that some parts of code are indented with tabs and some with spaces. Everything looks OK when using tab = 4 spaces to display code, but it gets really messy with other settings.

We are using git as VCS.
Is there any way to reformat entire code in repository, commit those changes AND **preserve "blame information"** somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible without rewriting history.

The easiest and most developer-friendly solution (which won't preserve blame information though) is fixing all whitespace issues in a single commit and then configuring git to reject commits adding mixed whitespace.

If rewriting history is not an issue for you (e.g. because you can ask all developers to throw away their local branches and fetch the rewritten ones), you could probably use `git filter-branch` to fix whitespace in all commits. This will not a new commit and thus ensure `git blame` shows correct information after the change.

Comment: I believe your answer is compimentary to that of @AndrejsCainikovs, as his would ensure new history gets written in a "neutral" way, and yours makes "old" history comply with the new requirement. Rewriting history to replace white-spaces shouldn't be too bad, these can be omitted from `diff` easily anyway.

Comment: Rewriting history is always bad unless you can either get **every single user** who cloned your repository to perform exactly the same rewriting (easy if you have a script and they just need to call it using git-filter-branch) or throw away their branches based on the old history.

Comment: you can also guide them into fetching the new stuff and cleverly rebase on top of it. We're talking about whitespace changes there... So it is much less difficult than if we were talking bigger changes.

Comment: I think I could go with rewriting the history. Team is not that big. However, what would happen if somebody didn't rewrite history (or didn't clone repository once again) and tried push to origin?

Comment: He'll get an error unless he pushes using `--force` (in that case he'd undo the history rewrite in the remote repo).

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own script that replaces tabs with desired amount of spaces (4 in your case), and place it in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.

Comment: Sure it will not. What you've committed will stay. But you can solve that by one separate commit :)

Comment: Which then makes git-blame useless unless you explicitely tell it to use whatever version was before the whitespace commit ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Actually, git blame has a -w option that ignores whitespace changes.

Comment: Can I set those hooks in central repository so they are cloned/fetched with changes?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But you could create a hook that checks the received commit if they introduce bad whitespace and in this case reject the push.

Answer (score -1):

A simple bash script can replace every tab to 4 spaces but you will have to use it before every commit...

Or, look at the settings of the differents ide to use tab instead of spaces. I know that emacs can do that. ;)